# Different animation times for transform parameters

Tags: css, transform

I'm writing a "3D navigation" where moving the mouse cursor subtlely rotates the contents of the screen. When something is clicked I want it to zoom (scale).

The rotation is achieved with transform property, and evoked when the cursor moves. This part works fine!

Now I want the scale to be animated at 500ms. But if I set this transition speed, it wrecks the nice smoothness of the cursor move property.

I tried solving with JavaScirpt, but the problem is that if I start working the "scale" segment alone, it overwrites the rotation property. CSS doesn't remember that I've set the rotation at some point, if I set transform again, during animation, with only the scale.

I have a work-around, but I don't think it's very nice and I suspect it will difficult to understand and refactor it in the future.

So like I can separate the timing for "background" and "color", is there a way to "go deeper", and also separate for the different transform properties?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which part did I do wrong? (except not posting code, but I doesn't really make a lot of sense in this case I think)

Comment: Except it does, you should at least have a fiddle of your working case and your question should be more pertinent. "Go deeper" is a question for marine biologists.

Comment: maybe place your content inside two parent containers, first would be rotate-responsible container, second scale-responsible. You can separate transform values then

Comment: I think that could do the trick, I'll try it out, Pawel. Thanks! :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gurgky2f/